# What is the minimum VSCode version that supports Web extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've published a VSCode extension.
Some users requested that I lower the minimum required VSCode engine version so that they can install the extension. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#visual-studio-code-compatibility

The extension is a VSCode Web extension (works on both local VSCode and vscode.dev).

It looks like the VSCode Web was officially released along with VSCode v1.62.0.

But that does not necessarily mean that my extension won't work in, say v1.53.0.

So, what is the minimum VSCode version that supports Web extensions?

Another reason I want to lower the version is that some of my users might be using Eclipse Theia (VSCode fork) which lags behind the VSCode versions.

Comment: It's going to be a risky move anyway if you don't have means to actually test it. The questions is of course legit.

Comment: Another reason I want to lower the version is that some of my users might be using Eclipse Theia (VSCode fork) which lags behind the VSCode versions.